# Is it possible to run javascript after a page has loaded using a omnibox extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

I am trying to build an omnibox extension. Essentially I want this extension to pull up a url, then wait for that url to load, then execute some simple javascript.

Not sure if it's appreciated to put long blocks of code in questions, please feel free to yell at me if not.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "AutoATR",
    "version": "0.1",
    "omnibox": { "keyword" : "atr" },
    "icons": {
      "16": "package.png"
    },
    "background": {
      "persistent": true,
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

background.js:

```
function resetDefaultSuggestion() {
  chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion({
  description: 'atr: Placeholder: %s'
  });
}
resetDefaultSuggestion();

function navigate(url) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
{
  chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: url});
  });
}

function finder(theID) {
  document.getElementById('theElement').value=theID
  document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[1].click()
}

chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(function() {
    // Navigate to URL
    navigate("https://theURL.com");
});

// **** Would like to wait for just this tab to load. 
// Then Execute finder(). ****
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you can do stuff in the address bar / omnibox like:  `javascript:alert('test');` - if you type that instead of a URL, it works.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like this?  `navigate(javascript:alert('test'););`

Comment: You have a tab ID. You wait for the appropriate event, just like any other tab/page load. Exactly which event you want to be watching will depend on when you are wanting to act with respect to the loading of the page. The normal ones to be listening to would be [`tabs.updated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated), or one of the [`webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) events (usually `onCompleted` or `onDOMContentLoaded`), depending on exactly what you need to know.

Comment: That's something I was also trying to figure out. How can I get the tabID for that tab? I've been trying to understand the documentation, but the examples are sparse.

Comment: Questions asking "Can I do X? / Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Overflow (SO) format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, it's usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for SO. In your case, the answer is "yes". Without more information from you, what you desire is not clear. (See prior comment). Where you have placed comments in your code is not in the program flow after the navigation, so we don't really know what you want.

Comment: You have the tab id: `tabs[0].id` in your `navigate()` function. You have already used `chrome.tabs.query()` to obtain it.

Comment: Is the URL you are navigating to static (never changes), or dynamic (changes)?

Comment: The URL is always the same.

Comment: My question is when I type "atr" + some text in the omnibox. I want the URL to load. Then when that URL is completely loaded, I want to run the finder("someText") function. I apologize, I am of course a novice and piecing this together from examples mostly. I am not sure how to explain what I am trying to do more clearly. I have a basic understanding of javascript and programming in general, but I dont understand the whole chrome api aspect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use manifest for your task:
change location in background script location of tab to your pathURL and in manifest.json add next code :

```
  "content_scripts": [{
            "matches": ["http://pathURL"],
            "js": ["js/script.js"]
        }]
```

js/script.js will be loaded after your browser tab path will match with "http://pathURL" pattern.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I usually have multiple instances of that tab open, and I don't want it to run on every tab. I'm also not sure how I would pass the text I entered into the omnibox to the script.js.

Comment: you can pass text from your omnibox through background page with help of chrome.runtime.sendMessage [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)